# Boolean field not saving in Django form

Tags: python, django

I have a form with radio buttons and text fields. When I submit the form, the boolean field does not get created in the record. The boolean field is supposed to be updated via the radio buttons. What could be the issue here?

Here is the relevant part of my forms.py file:

```
  CHOICES = (
        (1,'yes'),
        (0,'no')
    )

class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    one_time_service = forms.ChoiceField(required = True, choices = CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('one_time_service')
```

This is my models.py one_time_service field

```
one_time_service = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This is my views.py:

```
def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form= ServiceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            service_obj = form.save(commit=False)
            service_obj.user_id = request.user.id
            service_obj.save()
            return render_to_response('services/service_created.html', 
                              {'service': Service.objects.get(id=service_obj.id)})
    else:
        form = ServiceForm()

    args= {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('services/create_service.html', args )
```

Edit: Here is my create_service.html

```
<form action="/services/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<ul>
{{form.as_p}}
</ul>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Service">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried by putting TRUE and FALSE instead of 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. It doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea if this is the problem, but the line:

```
fields = ('one_time_service')
```

is wrong. That's not a single element tuple, that's a string with parens around it. Add a comma to make it a tuple:

```
fields = ('one_time_service',)
```

Edit: also, form.save() does not update any database records -- it creates a new one! That may be your problem.

Comment: Sorry, my question is a bit unclear. It is supposed to create a new record. The boolean field is one of many fields in the record that is to be created.

Comment: I will try the tuple solution and report back

Comment: That was it! Thanks. Turns out I forgot to add a comma at the very end of my Meta Class -which has a lot more fields than just one_time_service. Sorry if I didn't include all of the code, I just put what I thought was relevant. Thanks again!